# Where are the colors for the system theme (or just the gnome-terminal) specified in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, gnome-terminal

I really like the default color scheme for gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 14.04. I want to use it for my terminal color scheme in Xubuntu. The only problem is that I have not been able to find the configuration for the default color scheme in Ubuntu's gnome-terminal.

Is there a file in Ubuntu somewhere that specifies each color?

The best I could find was while checking the colors tab while editing the default profile. It has checked "use colors from system theme." Where are those specified?